# Increase Font on Browser-Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

I am one but a handful of programmers who are nearly 60 years old.  How can I increase the font on this otherwise very helpful app?  I find it hard to see.  Thanks very much.

http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Not sure why this question was down-voted.  Using neither Ctrl+ and the Ctrl-MouseWheel works on Chrome/Firefox on my machine (Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: Hmm, it works in Windows.  I don't know what the shortcut would be, but what about using Chrome's zoom feature through the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both IE and Chrome you can zoom in with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel.  This will make everything bigger (not just the fonts), but everything scales well in Regex Hero so it's not a problem.